# Strange ethernet behaviour of Ubuntu 14.04 on Fujitsu Esprimo P720 E90+

Tags: boot, networking, 14.04, ethernet, fujitsu-siemens

after I had openSuse running on this machine without Ethernet issues, I installed Ubuntu 14.04 and ran into a weired Ethernet problem. My colleague has Ubuntu 12.04 on the same type of computer and no issues.

My problem is, that approx. on 2 out of 3 times when I boot up, the Ethernet connection would take very long to establish and then still not work (ping would say "Destination Host unreachable").

Here's the output of ethtool eth0:

```
Settings for eth0:
Supported ports: [ TP ]
Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                        100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                        1000baseT/Full 
Supported pause frame use: No
Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                        100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                        1000baseT/Full 
Advertised pause frame use: No
Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
Speed: 1000Mb/s
Duplex: Full
Port: Twisted Pair
PHYAD: 2
Transceiver: internal
Auto-negotiation: on
MDI-X: off (auto)
    Cannot get wake-on-lan settings: Operation not permitted
Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
               drv probe link
Link detected: yes
```

and ethtool -i eth0:

```
driver: e1000e
version: 2.3.2-k
firmware-version: 0.13-4
bus-info: 0000:00:19.0
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: yes
supports-eeprom-access: yes
supports-register-dump: yes
supports-priv-flags: no
```

Did someone ever have similar problems? Where should I start looking for a solution?

Thanks!

**Edit 1**
Here's the output of dmesg | grep eth0 on non-working state, if it helps somehow:

```
dmesg | grep eth0
[    1.800540] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: registered PHC clock
[    1.800542] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: (PCI Express:2.5GT/s:Width x1) 90:1b:0e:1b:07:79
[    1.800543] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
[    1.800593] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: MAC: 11, PHY: 12, PBA No: FFFFFF-0FF
[    7.018035] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[    7.910448] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[    7.910657] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   24.366988] e1000e: eth0 NIC Link is Up 100 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
[   24.366991] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: 10/100 speed: disabling TSO
[   24.367023] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
```

**Edit 2**

So, I guess, I should do a bug report. Does someone have suggestions on which useful information and context I should collect before reporting the bug?